# Assigning multiple column's value from oracle query to multiple variables in Unix

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I need to read values of 10 columns from oracle query and assign the same to 10 unix variables. The query will return only one record(row).

I tried to append all these columns using a delimiter(;) in the select query and assign the same to a single variable(V) in unix. I thought I could use 'cut' and assign values to all the required 10 variables from V.

But the thing is some of the the columns have special character and it is kind of hard for me to cut out the required details. Sometimes the delimiter(;)itself is present in column value. Also the code is very lengthy.

Is there a better way to assign multiple column values from query to unix variables.?

Also when i read '-e' from query and pass it unix varaible it becomes '?e'. Is there anyway we could solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @harish, can you show what you have done ...?

Comment: Hi Andy. I don't have the actual code with me right now. But i did something like this.......... unix_var=( select 'c1=' ||c1||';'|| 'c2=' ||c2 ||... from table).. unix_var will now have the single row of all the column values along with name delimited by ';'... I want to assign these values to 10 unix varaibles.. v1,v2,... v10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, depending on what you want to achieve. Here is one particular case with ; as a delimiter. However, you can always use the default space delimiter.

```
variable=$($ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /  as sysdba <<EOF
set head off
set verify off
set feedback off
select sysdate || ';' || systimestamp from dual;
exit;
EOF
)

sysdate=$(echo $variable | awk -F ';' '{print $1}')
echo 'col1:'$sysdate

systimestamp=$(echo $variable | awk -F ';' '{print $2}')
echo 'col2:'$systimestamp
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply.

I am new to shell scripting.

Please explain me..... awk -F ';' '{print $1}'

will it look for first occurance of delimiter and print value accordingly?

Also if my coulm value has space in between,

eg: col2='Have a nice day'.

In the above case will {print $2} give the complete value of the column.

Comment: `awk -F ';' '{print $1}'` will break the string into columns, separated by ;. $1 variable will contain the first column, $2 the second and so on. $0 is the whole line. You can use `awk '{print $1}'` to break the string into columns using the default delimiter - space - and print the first column.  There are other ways to do it, however, you can do it with cut, read, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Since I don't have the system now I am unable to try it..sorry for that.. consider select c1||;||c2 from table..let c1='Good morning'. If i use the above code, I am expecting col1='Good morning'. Will I get the full value or only 'Good'. Please explain. My column values can have any number of spaces in them. That is my concern. Sorry for asking everthing. I am not able to try it practically now.. Thanks

Comment: If you will separate the string with ; then you'll get everything between ;

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will try the same tomorrow and update the post. Do you also have any solution for reading '-e'? In the oracle query it is correctly getting read as '-e'. But in the unix when i print it becomes '?e' (Actually ?is a inverted. Not sure how to type it. So using ?). I am not sure how this junk value comes..

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how you get this value. Probably, it has something to do with your character set. You need to understand what character set you have configured in your database (nls_database_parameters), whether you set another character set in your session (shell, sqlplus, sql deverloper) or maybe you have the wrong character set in your ssh-client (putty, mobaxterm or something).

Comment: Thanks again. The code is working perfectly. Appreciate your kindly help :)

Comment: The problem was with the invalid hypen!. Please refer this link .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761044/inverted-question-mark-e-appears-in-unix-variable-after-getting-it-from-oracle/34762490#34762490