# Inverted question mark(¿e) appears in unix variable after getting it from oracle query

Tags: oracle, shell, variables, unix

I am assigning oracle query result to unix variable. In the query result the column has `-e` as value. When i assign this to a unix variable, it becomes `¿e` . How to overcome this junk value?

Comment: it would be nice to add into the question a minimum verifiable example of code. For example: `"var=bla bla; echo var;"`

Comment: Are you sure it's a normal hyphen in the database, not a non-ASCII variant that your client can't display (and that Unix wouldn't recognise as a flag anyway)? Perhaps as when Word helpfully replaces `-` with `—`? You can use the `dump()` function to figure out what the actual stored character is.

Comment: Alex..great thought.. The issue was with hyphen.. It looks exactly the same thought. The issue is now resolved. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with hyphen.. `- / —`.

`'—'` is an invalid hyphen. I had corrected the same with `'-'`.

The issue is resolved now.